# Angular 4 template reference variables

Tags: angular, material-design, angular2-template, angular-material2, angular-components

is it possible to have a dynamic template reference variable?

for example, i would like to do something like this:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i=index" >
  <th >{{i}}</th>
  <td>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput matDatepicker="{{'pick'+i}}" placeholder="date" 
      formControlName="date">

      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix for="{{'pick'+i}}">
      </mat-datepicker-toggle>

      <mat-datepicker #"{{'pick'+i}}"></mat-datepicker>

    </mat-form-field>

  </td>
 </tr>
```

I am trying to figure out how to write `<mat-datepicker #"{{'pick'+i}}"></mat-datepicker>` such that the reference variable is dynamic with the loop index.  Using interpolation here just to explain what I am trying to achieve.

regards
Adisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template reference variable inside embedded view(*ngFor) has its own scope so you can just use the same name:

```
<tr *ngFor...>
    ...
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pick" placeholder="date" formControlName="date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pick"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #pick></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/Nw3Uh94hjdiaKDO4ARio?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: the documentation seems to contradict this, but it works!  ['Do not define the same variable name more than once in the same template'](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-)

Answer (score 1):

Template reference variables cannot be named dynamically. They must be statically analysable

Have a look  [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4581#issuecomment-148786554) where you have other suggestions on reaching the goal